# How to push my local default Meteor Mongo db's data to Heroku mLabs for app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, heroku

I set up my app data in my local dev Meteor environment using the default Mongo db that installed with Meteor. My app is ready to deploy on Heroku, but I intended for my data to go with it (similar to Rails "migrate").

In Heroku, I added the mLabs plugin and set the "MONGO_URL" variable. How do I get my local app db pushed to my mLabs instance for my deployment on Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me.

**1. make a dump of my local mongo db**

In terminal (NOT mongo shell) in the app folder,

```
mongodump --port=3001 -o ../dump
```

**2. move the db files out of the "dump/my-db-name" folder up into "dump"**

In my local meteor instance, the "dump" folder was placed in the folder above my app, so "dump" was in the same directory as my app's folder. "dump" contained a folder named after my database ("dump/my-database-name/"). This caused the next script to fail with a mongorestore error "don't know what to do with 'my-database-name'".  To prevent the error, I moved all of the files in the folder "my-database-name" up into "dump", then deleted the "my-database-name" folder.

By default, the meteor app creates with database name "meteor", so for anyone browsing this question who hasn't changed the db name, it will be "dump/meteor/".

**4. Push the dumped database to the Heroku app's mLabs instance.** I had already added the mLabs plugin in my Heroku app, and set the "MONGO_URL" in my Heroku app config. If these aren't done, they must be done first.

In terminal (NOT mongo shell), change from the app's directory to the directory that holds the "dump" directory.

Get the default "import" script for the Heroku app's mLabs instance by going to the mLabs plugin, and click the "Tools" tab.  The script provided here did not work for me, but it may work for someone else, and it did provide the variables I used in the modified script below.

**3. If the "import" script provided in mLabs tools did not work...**

In mLabs "Users" tab, create a user with admin privileges.

Then, use this script with your variables replacing bracketed variables (replace the brackets, also).

```
mongorestore -h [your mLabs value]  -d [your mLabs default user name] -u [your mLabs created user name] -p [your mLabs created user's password]
```

After the script runs, you should be able to refresh your mLabs "Collections" tab and see your pushed data.

Good luck :)  I hope this helps someone!